# Common term to a position of an absolute pin or a potential discovery check

Tags: terminology, pins, discovered-check

is there any chess term to describe a position where the opponent's king is shielded from a check by only 1 piece (regardless if it's your piece, which would make it a potential discovery check, or the opponent's one, which would make that one piece absolutely pinned)?

Comment: You may want to clarify if your question concerns standard chess play, or if deals with the more artificial world of chess problem composition, where there are numerous technical terms of interest to other problemists, but comparatively uninteresting to anyone else.  Your use of the term 'absolutely pinned'  seems to be one used outside the problem world.

Comment: @user30536 I'm working on a small program and I just need to find an appropriate, preferably short, name for a thing. Currently I ended on choosing 'opponentKingSinglePieceShielded', but may be there is a shorter, more common name for such a position

Comment: What about opponentKingSingleBlocker?

Comment: @Hank'sbackrank thank you, it may indeed suffice, but I'm asking here about an 'official' term. 'No term' is also an answer, and I guess it's the one

Comment: There is the term 'half-pin' for the situations where there are two pieces shielding the king: if one moves, the other is forced to stay.  If that's half a pin, you seem to be looking for a full pin.  However, I'm not sure I get the significance of 'absolute pin' so ...

Comment: Problem chess has the term "masked line", which is independent of the color of the masking piece...but the line points on a neighboring field, i.e. not necessarily on the king. So as a programmer I might use "MaskedCheck".

Comment: @dk Is the question you wish to ask : " Is there a chess term ( in standard chess ) for the position where a king is sheilded by a piece of either colour from a check ?'

Comment: @schweppz yes, it could be rephrased this way too " Is there a chess term ( in standard chess ) for the position where a king is shielded by a *single* piece of either colour from a check"

Comment: @dk asked the other way leads to getting bogged down in heap of other terms ( like absolute pin and discovered attack etc) which detracts from what is actually being asked .It might be redited this way then .